# JavaScript Print PDF using Adobe toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, pdf, iframe

I am trying to print a PDF in an iFrame. I have a print button for the user to click. I am finding it hard to write JavaScript to print the PDF that will work across IE, Chrome, Firefox. It's been really hard to print PDF, in an Iframe, in particular on IE.

While working on this, I noticed a toolbar for saving and printing the PDF when hovered over the PDF. I think these features are offered by Adobe.

I would like to know if there is a way to access these Adobe PDF controls through JavaScript.
How can I fire them using the print button?

[image: Iframe PDF Adobe]

Comment: In which browser were you when you took that screenshot?

Comment: @MaxWyss .. IE Version 11

Comment: I have a similar looking PDF viewing window in Chrome, and I do not have an active PDF viewer plug-in. That would mean that it is IE which provides your PDF viewing component. As the PDF viewing component of IE is pretty basic (aka dumb), there is no access to Acrobat JavaScrip, and if you try to print using JavaScript, you'd have to concentrate on how you can control the PDF viewing component of IE.